# Convergent but not consistent nor stable Euler method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Sorry for posting all the definitions (I think they may vary from book to book), so to be sure:

> Given a function $f:I\times\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$, where $I=[t_0,t_0+T]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and the Cauchy problem
>   $$y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$$
>   $$y(t_0)=\eta$$
>   its Euler method for the partition $P=\{t_0<t_1<\dots<t_N=t_0+T\}$ of $I$ (with diameter $h$) is
>   $$y_0=\eta_h$$
>   $$y_{n+1}=y_n+h_nf(t_n,y_n)$$
>   for $0\le n\le N-1$, where $h_n=t_{n+1}-t_n$
>
> We say the method is $\textbf{convergent}$ if, given any solution $y(t)$ of the equation we have
>   $$\max |y(t_n)-y_n|\to0\quad\text{when}\quad h\to0\quad\text{and}\quad\Vert\eta_h-\eta\Vert\to0$$
>   The method is $\textbf{stable}$ if there exists constants $h^*,M>0$ such that, given any partition $P=\{t_0<t_1<\dots<t_N=t_0+T\}$ with diameter $h\le h^*$ and any three sets $\{u_n\}_{n=0}^N$, $\{v_n\}_{n=0}^N$ and $\{w_n\}_{n=0}^N$ with
>   $$u_{n+1}=u_n+h_nf(t_n,u_n)$$
>   $$v_{n+1}=v_n+h_nf(t_n,v_n)+w_m$$
>   we have
>   $$\Vert u_n-v_n\Vert\le M(\Vert u_0-v_0\Vert +\sum_{k=0}^n\Vert w_k\Vert)$$
>   And the method is $\textbf{consistent}$ if, given any solution $y(t)$ of the equation we have
>   $$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\Vert y(t_n+h_n)-y(t_n)-h_nf(t_n,y_n)\Vert\to0\quad\text{when}\quad h\to0\quad\text{and}\quad\Vert\eta_h-\eta\Vert\to0$$

The following is true:

$\textbf{Theorem:}$ If the method is stable and consistent, then it is convergent.

I'm looking for particular examples of "nice" (continuous, lipschitz) functions $f$ and methods that are

1. Convergent but not stable and/or consistent
2. Stable but not convergent
3. Consistent but not convergent

and relatively easy to check.

Thanks!